# When I build my app my simulator looks different from my viewcontroller.xib

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I was making a user interface using storyboards and when I built my app to see how it would look in the iOS simulator it didn't look like the viewcontroller in the storyboard (some of the buttons were moved around and I had to move one button way down so it was in the place i wanted it to be). Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reason is auto layout, it will automatically position elements on a relative basis depending on the device you're running.

You can turn autolayout off, or build for all devices at once and keep it on.

You may want to read iOS Auto Layout Demystified by Erica Sadun which goes in depth to the world of autolayout.

Comment: Note that even without autolayout (using the old "springs and struts"), your views can be resized.